# Under what conditions is $J\cdot M$ an $R$-submodule of $M$?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, ideals

I have that $M$ is an $R$-module where $R$ is commutative and unitary ring. Supposing that $J$ is an ideal of $R$, when is the set $J \cdot M$ an $R$-submodule of $M$?

I have to check the two axioms of an $R$-submodule. First that $(J\cdot M,+)$ is a subgroup of $(M,+)$ and this is the hard part. Second that for $r \in R$ and $x \in J \cdot M$, $rx \in J \cdot M$ and this is always true. But for the first axiom I don't know what to do.

$J \cdot M$ is the set $\{jm, j \in J, m \in M\}$ (as seems from where I am reading)

Thanks for help.

Comment: The standard definition of $JM$ is the set of all sums of elements of the form $jm$, not just elements of the form $jm$.

Comment: I have only ever seen trivial criteria for this, and that is usually why the definition is as Eric Wofsey describes. Where did you find the problem? It is not a very good exercise (if that's what it is), depending on your level.

Comment: @rschwieb it is not an exercise. I am reading a proof of a theorem: "If a free $R$-module has a  finite basis, then any two bases of it have the same cardinality", where $R$ is a commutative unitary ring. First, they say $R$ has at least one maximal ideal $I$, and that $R/I$ is a field. Then, they claim that $M/I\cdotM$ is an $R/I$-vector space. I was trying to understand why would $IM$ be an $R$-submodule of $M$; the author isn't clear about what $IM$ is, but for some weird reason, I thought it should be as was defined in the question.

Comment: So I thought that it might have to do with $I$ being maximal or $M$ being finitely generated. Hence my question.

Comment: @madmatician That information makes all the difference! Thanks for posting it!

Comment: @rschwieb and thanks a lot for your time! Your answers have been a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment describing the context of the situation, (thank you for that, by the way) it's clear that the text intends to use the standard definition of the product:

$JM:=\{\sum j_i m_i\mid j\in J, m\in M, i\in I \text{ for a finite index set $I$ }\}$

This is what is intended when looking at any sort of ideal- or module-wise product in ring theory, precisely because the group-theoretic version ($HK:=\{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$) does not produce an acceptable result in the presence of both $+$ and $\cdot$ operations.